# MySQL and PHP query using columns for headings and rows output based on corresponding heading

Tags: php, mysql

[image]I am trying to do two things, have column heading output ($accounts) and then have the corresponding sum(z.cost) added under the corresponding column, say Water Rates. As well as grouping as there are many records per property. It should look like:

```
Property                     Council Rates              Water Rates
6 Hudson Road Rosemeadow          $1000                     $150
121 New York Street New York City $500
```

At the moment it outputs every property row individually, and all only in the first column, Council Rates.

The code is below:

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class='text-center'>Property</th>
        <?php
        $query_prop = "SELECT a.street_number,
                         a.street_name,
                         a.suburb,
                         z.services, 
                         z.cost, 
                         j.service_type 
                         FROM pms_property a 
                         LEFT JOIN pms_holding_costs z 
                          ON z.pms_fk_id = a.pms_id 
                         LEFT JOIN pms_accounts j 
                          ON j.service_type = z.services 
                         WHERE z.services IS NOT NULL";

        $accounts = "SELECT service_type FROM pms_accounts";
        $value = $newdb->mysqlquery($query_prop);
        $acc = $newdb->mysqlquery($accounts);

        while ($acc1 = mysqli_fetch_array($acc)) {
            echo "<th class='text-center'>$acc1[0]</th>";
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($value)) {
        echo "<tr class='odd gradeX'><td>$row[0] $row[1] $row[2]</td> ";
        if ($row['service_type'] == $acc1['service_type']) {
            echo "<td>$$row[4]</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>$0</td></tr>";
        }
    } ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" class="text-right"><strong>Total Costs</strong></td>
        <td colspan="1"><strong>$<?php echo $row1[1]; ?></strong></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class='text-center'>Property</th>


                                        <th class='text-center'>Council Rates</th>



                                        <th class='text-center'>Water Rates</th>


                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>


                                    <tr class='odd gradeX'>
                                        <td>6 Hudson Road Rosemeadow</td> 

                                                <td>$0</td>
                                                </tr>

                                    <tr class='odd gradeX'>
                                        <td>121 New York Street New York City</td> 

                                                <td>$0</td>
                                                </tr>

                                    <tr class='odd gradeX'>
                                        <td>6 Hudson Road Rosemeadow</td> 

                                                <td>$0</td>
                                                </tr>

                                    <tr class='odd gradeX'>
                                        <td>6 Hudson Road Rosemeadow</td> 

                                                <td>$0</td>
                                                </tr>

                                    <tr class='odd gradeX'>
                                        <td>6 Hudson Road Rosemeadow</td> 

                                                <td>$0</td>
                                                </tr>

                                    <tr class='odd gradeX'>
                                        <td>6 Hudson Road Rosemeadow</td> 

                                                <td>$0</td>
                                                </tr>

                                    <tr class='odd gradeX'>
                                        <td>6 Hudson Road Rosemeadow</td> 

                                                <td>$0</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                                                        <tr>
                                        <td colspan="1" class="text-right"><strong>Total Costs</strong></td>
                                        <td colspan="1"><strong>$1650</strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

[image]

Comment: `$$row[4]`  - `variable variable` or mistake.  This is bad too `" ... $0  ... "`  try this `"...  \$0  ... "`  You have to escape the `$` in double quoted strings (for money) as PHP will do variable interpolation on it (probably).

Comment: Hi ArtisticPhoenix, the $$row[4] is a mistake, i changed it, not joy joy, also did \$0 no joy either, but thank you so much for helping!!!! :-)

Comment: Are the table headers present at least?  Can you post the current HTML that is generated by the page.  Or enough to show what is missing.   P.S.  usiing `$$var` 2 dollar signs is actually a thing in PHP, its a `variable named variable` it's very rarely used however, and pretty much a "legacy" feature.

Comment: Ok I added HTML, and a picture of the screen shot. The headers output it is just the row data against each column not working atm. still fiddling with it.

Comment: If I remove this line if ($row['services'] == $acc1['service_type'] ) to if ($row['services'] ) the data outputs in the first column, which is great, but one of the rows should go into the second column, but it stays in the first column with the rest.

Comment: am I correct in thinking there are no `pms_accounts` that have a `service_type` of `water rates` ?  If so then I know what is going on,.  It seems like in your `$query_prop` your not getting any records associated with that service.

Comment: in pms_accounts there are two service_types, council rates and water rates. The column headings wouldn't show up if they not there ,,, the column headings are pulled from pms_accounts

Comment: It would be nice if this was setup in https://www.db-fiddle.com/ So I could see the query.  It's hard to visualize 2 left joins in my head.  If you can set the tables up in there an the data that would be awesome, you can get the table easy, with `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` and then put it in there, and save it.

Comment: That's not true, because they are separate queries, there is no correlation between the data and the headers.  There is no Guarantee that a relationship exists in such a way that would return both in the query results for the data. ( ie,you could have 2 types in there with one that has no related data ) Even if it did you may get 2 rows, one for each type, not both types together.  I say may because of the `visualizing` thing.  I'd need to see it.

Comment: Yea, I would have to see the schema of your DB to help you further because this seems weird `LEFT JOIN pms_accounts j ON j.service_type = z.services`  its not an ID so is it a `VARCHAR` is `services` a single service_type or a list of them.  Or, is it really an ID, I have no way to know.  I can tell you if its a Many to One, you will get 2 rows where you currently expect 1, One for each service type, and that would explain why you have one service type.

Comment: Ok I have done that it is on db-fiddle now

Comment: Um, you have to save it and post the link...  Like this, it's the best I could do, but even this will show you what I mean by you get 2 rows where you expect 1   https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iw37qXTxiMqUEjCCK7FcjL/0

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jCyHynBPPv6DMWTa2G6NYC/0#&togetherjs=13Hpt4nS4D

Comment: I am pretty much done, it's not 100% exactly what you need but it should be like 95% of the way there.

Comment: Now you owe me like $50 that was a lot of work....  lol

Comment: haha maybe a beer or few... this is great work thank you, I am still adapting th array into the output, the array is awesome, but now i am getting it out into the columns. Thank you!!!!

Comment: see new picture

Comment: did you change this `mysqli_fetch_array` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.  You need the database results with the field names as keys in an associative array.  And with Mysqli that's how it's done.

Comment: You also have to add `a.pms_id` to the SQL query.  It wont work without the properties primary key.

Comment: Magic! Yep I added pms_id back in a while ago. Im getting this weird index error  that isnt on the sandbox. Undefined index: Water Rates.....the array and data is ok, not sure where it is coming from ub the $headers are including both council and water properly.

Comment: Oh and yes I changed to mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: Make sure you didn't miss this line `$default = array_fill_keys($headers,'0');`  I also went and added a pretty in depth explanation of how it all works in comments for you.  It's important to learn how to do it, and why it does what it does.  That may help you trouble shoot any issues, as some variables and what not are probably different then what you have.

Comment: You would have to build this `$headers` array, in the first `while` loop, I didn't cover that in the answer.

Comment: give me a few minutes and I will post the complete code.

Comment: Yep im getting there. I have data in the two columns now, both are the same data not seperated by headers, working on that now.

Comment: There, it's at the bottom of that mile long answer....  Probably run SO database out of room... ha ha.  If you haven't noticed i'm a bit of a stickler on my tabs and formatting, readability is `#1`, `#2` is performance, `#3` is functionality and `#4` is maintainability / reusability

Comment: Man your a legend, the code is beautiful! I was nearly there but you just put the icing on the cake. Well done and thank you so much!!!

Comment: Sure just make sure to accept the answer, good timing, my server at work is about to crash .. running out of Hard drive space ... again.

Comment: I just ticked your answer. Dude your a awesome code machine! I changed some of the sql sum the cost, group by the pms_id and services and it is working a treat!!! Thank you so so much.....sorry to crash your server haha

Comment: Yea me, to it has like 56 GB of ram, and1T of SSD HD space that is all used up.  ( its my works server )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes from the data query, there is nothing inherently wrong with the Query, its just the data is not formatted in the way you expected, or needed it to be.

***PROBLEM***

```
SELECT
    a.street_number,
    a.street_name,
    a.suburb,
    z.services, 
    z.cost, 
    j.service_type 
FROM
    pms_property a 
LEFT JOIN
    pms_holding_costs z ON z.pms_fk_id = a.pms_id 
LEFT JOIN
    pms_accounts j ON j.service_type = z.services 
WHERE
    z.services IS NOT NULL
```

HERE you basically have a Many to Many relationship,  Many Properties can have Many Accounts.

Now in your Html you build the headers using this

```
"SELECT service_type FROM pms_accounts"
```

Which gives you this array ( basically )

```
['Council Rates','Water Rates']
```

All the service types, this is also "uncorallated" to the other query. That just means there is no direct relationship between the two, they are separate queries after all.

You are expecting 2 values from `z.cost` or `$row[4] ( 0 based indexing )`  one for each of your service types.  But if you look at the query ( above ) you can see that field is present only one time.  So there is no logical way you could get 2 values for that in only one row.

Don't worry, we can fix this with PHP.  There are ways to fix this using SQL, but they would be a problem if you added any service types ( we'll cover this more latter ).

This DBfiddle should help illustrate the issue. This is not your exact schema, I removed the "superficial" columns, because only the relationships between the tables are what is important.

```
pms_id  |       services    |   service_type
    1   |   Council Rates   |   Council Rates  //property (id 1) with only one service
    2   |   Council Rates   |   Council Rates  //property (id 2) with 2 services, 1 of 2
    2   |   Water Rates     |   Water Rates    //property (id 2) with 2 services, 2 of 2
```

This is the structure you want,

```
pms_id  |   Council Rates   |   Water Rates | ...
    1   |    {cost}         |   {cost}   
    2   |    {cost}         |   {cost}
```

***SOLUTION***

First thing is we are going to need the primary ID for the properties, so we an uniquely identify is.  So add it to the data query,

```
SELECT
    a.pms_id, #<--------- add the ID
    a.street_number,
    a.street_name,
    a.suburb,
    z.services, 
    z.cost, 
    j.service_type 
FROM
    pms_property a
```

Then, we are going to have to hang onto the `$accounts`, I will call them `$headers` because they go in the head of the `table`.  They are the results from this query

```
"SELECT service_type FROM pms_accounts"
```

Ok, so where you loop over that result set with the `while` loop. We just need to create an array and save the data in it. Like this:

```
$headers = [];
while ($acc1 = mysqli_fetch_array($acc)) {
     $headers[] = $acc1[0];
     echo "<th class='text-center'>$acc1[0]</th>";
}
```

For these examples and tests I have to use some "Canned" data that mirrors your data, as I cant really do it with a Database online. So this is the basic structure your data is in from the 2 queries, right now {as it stands}.

```
$headers = ['Council Rates','Water Rates'];

$rows = [
    ['pms_id' => 1, 'street_name' => 'ONE', 'service_type' => 'Council Rates', 'cost' => 100],
    ['pms_id' => 2, 'street_name' => 'TWO', 'service_type' => 'Council Rates', 'cost' => 100],
    ['pms_id' => 2, 'street_name' => 'TWO', 'service_type' => 'Water Rates', 'cost' => 200],
];
```

We have to change that into something more "useful" and meaningful to the task at hand.

```
//We will need the result from the first query, the one for the headers. 
$headers = ['Council Rates','Water Rates']; 

/*
   first: create a "template" array by using $headers as the keys and
   fill them with 0 for the value {cost = 0, when missing}
   ----------------------------------------------------
   example. ['Council Rates'=>'0','Water Rates'=>'0']
   ----------------------------------------------------
*/
$default = array_fill_keys($headers,'0');  

$data = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($value)) {
   //instead of mysqli_fetch_array, see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php
   $service_type = $row['service_type'];

   /*
      Create a key based on the properties primary id
      ----------------------------------------------------
      I like to put a string "r" ( or anything ) in front
      of it so it doesn't get mistaken for a meaningless
      numeric index, because it's critical that we have it.     
   */
   $key = 'r'.$row['pms_id']; //such as 'r345'

    if( !isset($data[$key])){
        //if not set then it's the first pass ( Setup ) for this property

        //Create a new item with the service name as the key, and cost as the value
        $row[$service_type] = $row['cost'];

        //remove the type and cost they will just get in the way now.
        unset($row['service_type'], $row['cost']);

        /*
           by merging $row "header template" we made earlier {$default}
           ------------------------------------------------
           ['Council Rates'=>'0','Water Rates'=>'0']
           ------------------------------------------------
           we insure that any {$header} values, have a corresponding
           key in {$row}. This way there are no missing index issues,
           and we won't have to check if they have that service because
           any that don't will be conveniently filled with a '0'
           -----------------------------------------------
           example: ['pms_id' => 1, 'Council Rates'=>'100','Water Rates'=>'0']
           ----------------------------------------------------
        */
        $row =  array_merge( $default, $row);

        /*
            lastly add to our data array with our primary ID based key
            this loop iteration, is complete
        */
        $data[$key] = $row;

    }else{
        /*
             Additional passes, we only need the cost and service type.
             Because the properties {pms_id} is the primary key, and we
             have that in our sql as well as in $data from the previous
             loop iteration, we can easily find and fill in the next 
             service type. 

             -note- were not creating the service type, because we did 
              that with the {$default} array, we are simply replacing
              the '0' cost placeholder from that operation. 
             Any properties that are missing a service type will just 
             leave that 0 there.
        */
        $data[$key][$service_type] = $row['cost'];
    }
} 

//print_r($data);
```

This Outputs:

```
$data = Array(
    [r1] => Array(
        [Council Rates] => 100
        [Water Rates] => 0
        [pms_id] => 1
        [street_name] => ONE
    )
[r2] => Array(
        [Council Rates] => 100
        [Water Rates] => 200
        [pms_id] => 2
        [street_name] => TWO
    )
)
```

You can test this part here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa938ec823f8f116432eadad1f6db991e4be37dd

As you can see, we now have the keys we want for the service types and this data is structured in a way that will let us easily create the HTML output we need.  This will make the output part almost trivial.

So where you output the data ( before with a wile loop, and read it from the database ) we will use a `foreach` loop instead.

These two operations have to be done separate.  There is no guarantee on the order of the data, so we can't process it a few rows at a time and do the output in the same loop.  It's not a big deal because we have reduced the size of the data array by combining the rows.

```
    //$headers = ['Council Rates','Water Rates']; //for readability

    foreach($data as $row) {
        echo "<tr class='odd gradeX'>";

        echo "<td>{$row['street_number']} {$row['street_name']} {$row['suburb']}</td>";

        /*
           Dynamically loop over headers.  We could just type this in
           but if you wanted to add more service types latter you would 
           have to come back here and add them in.  This way, you wont
           have to touch it in that case.

           This also enforces the order, we need the costs for each 
           service_type to be output in the same exact order the
           service_type headers were added into the table ( <th> ). 
         */
        foreach($headers as $header ){

            /*
              We have each service_type as a key in {$row}
              so we just pull it out with the {$header}.
            */              
            echo "<td>{$row[$header]}</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Outputs 
-note- I'm missing `street_number` and `suburb` in my example data, but it shouldn't matter ( In the Real stuff ).

```
<tr class='odd gradeX'>
    <td> ONE </td>
    <td>100</td> <!-- Council Rates -->
    <td>0</td> <!-- Water Rates -->
</tr>

<tr class='odd gradeX'>
    <td> TWO </td>
    <td>100</td> <!-- Council Rates -->
    <td>200</td> <!-- Water Rates -->
</tr>
```

You can test this here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6192b8fc732a88f212daed91423b180fd78ec4b9

Doing it in PHP is better because, if we did this with a query it would be static, and if you added another service type we would have to edit the query, and the output.  This way in PHP you should have to make virtual no code changes if you add more services.  It's my experience over time, things grow needs change, you don't want to have to revisit this code every time that happens. As Developers we should always look to the future, and make the code as future proof and maintainable as possible.

So much for a "short" answer, well it was fun.  As I mentioned in the comments please take the time to look over the comments in the above code because it's more important to learn and understand then to just get a working piece of code.
Here is the full code:

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Property</th>
        <?php 
            //for debugging
            error_reporting(-1);
            ini_set('display_errors', -1);

            $accounts = "SELECT service_type FROM pms_accounts";
            $acc = $newdb->mysqlquery($accounts);
            $headers = [];
        ?>        
        <?php while ($acc1 = mysqli_fetch_array($acc)){ ?>
            <?php $headers[] = $acc1[0]; ?>
            <th class="text-center"><?php echo $acc1[0]; ?></th>
        <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
          $default = array_fill_keys($headers,'0');

          $query_prop = "
                SELECT
                    a.pms_id,
                    a.street_number,
                    a.street_name,
                    a.suburb,
                    z.services,
                    z.cost,
                    j.service_type
                 FROM
                    pms_property a
                 LEFT JOIN
                    pms_holding_costs z ON z.pms_fk_id = a.pms_id
                 LEFT JOIN
                    pms_accounts j ON j.service_type = z.services
                 WHERE
                     z.services IS NOT NULL
             ";

          $value = $newdb->mysqlquery($query_prop);

          $data = [];
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($value)){
              $service_type = $row['service_type'];

              //row unique id
              $key = 'r'.$row['pms_id']; 

              if( !isset($data[$key])){
                  //if not set then it's the first pass ( Setup ) for this property

                  //Create a new item with the service name as the key, and cost as the value
                  $row[$service_type] = $row['cost'];

                  //remove the type and cost they will just get in the way now.
                  unset($row['service_type'], $row['cost']);

                  $row =  array_merge( $default, $row);
                  $data[$key] = $row;
              }else{
                  //Additional passes set just the service type cost
                  $data[$key][$service_type] = $row['cost'];
              }
          } 
        ?>
        <?php foreach($data as $row){ ?>
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td>
                    <?php echo "{$row['street_number']} {$row['street_name']} {$row['suburb']}"; ?>
                </td> 
            <?php foreach($headers as $header){ ?>             
                <td><?php echo $row[$header]; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>  
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="text-right"><strong>Total Costs</strong></td>
                <td colspan="1"><strong>$<?php echo $row1[1]; ?></strong></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I shared the fiddle with you mate. I have implemented your code to the letter and still getting no results as per the image I posted. I will try removing the service_type and see what happens.

Comment: You mean you shared one that doesn't run, but I guess I can fix that first. because your missing the `;` after each bit of SQL, mate.

Comment: Hi @ArtisticPhoenix! I have been using your solution for some time now and it works wonderfully I have to thank you for that, I have hit a snag though now trying to add a total row to the table. Using the `foreach ($headers as $header`) I can get the total output for the last row, but not for the entire column, how can I get the loop to sum the whole column, I have tried += $value etc to no avail as it comes through as string. Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I would need more info like the name of the field your trying to sum, but I would suggest posting it as a separate question.  I would also say to include the array you are trying to get the sum of, or an example array.

Comment: No worries @ArtisticPhoenix I will make a new question now.

Comment: New Question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977936/totalling-columns-on-generated-output-php-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I've probably made a total Bodge up of this but the intention is to show a few things...

**Variable Naming** - reading the code as it stands makes my head spin... Call things what they are... How you do that is open to opinion but have something...

I've added lots of comments but more importantly - to get things going - I have added in some debug information in the form of var_dump().

This is so "we" can at least view what you are actually getting and not what you "think" you are getting... 
Because when there are issues - that is usually the case

I've "Attempted" to point out that using field names in database results is much much much nicer than using numeric indexes because a 0 to n is not very descriptive. So to that end I've made up what I can glean from the supplied code.

So the new code - Not tested and not directly answering your question but should help us move forward by seeing what you get from the var_dumps ( You have to uncomment those. )

Hopefully the comments in the code help explain what is going on.
NOTE: This is Not Tested.

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class='text-center'>Property</th>
        <?php
        $property_query = "SELECT a.street_number,
                         a.street_name,
                         a.suburb,
                         z.services, 
                         z.cost, 
                         j.service_type 
                         FROM pms_property a 
                         LEFT JOIN pms_holding_costs z 
                          ON z.pms_fk_id = a.pms_id 
                         LEFT JOIN pms_accounts j 
                          ON j.service_type = z.services 
                         WHERE z.services IS NOT NULL";
        // I am assuming ( badly ) that $property_result is an associative array.
        $property_result = $newdb->mysqlquery($property_query);
        // To check for debug purposes - uncomment the line below
        // var_dump($property_result);

        $accounts_query = "SELECT service_type FROM pms_accounts";

        // I am assuming ( badly ) that $accounts_result is an associative array.
        $accounts_result = $newdb->mysqlquery($accounts_query);
        // To check for debug purposes - uncomment the line below
        // var_dump($account_result);


        // Looks like this is an array of an array which has the table column names?
        while ($account = mysqli_fetch_array($accounts_result)) {
            echo "<th class='text-center'>$account[0]</th>";
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    // Use MYSQLI_ASSOC to return the result set as an Associative Array.
    // Using numeric Indexes is hard to read and debug and prone to errors.
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($property_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        // Wrap variables in {} to help PHP work out what is a Variable in a double quoted string.
        echo "<tr class='odd gradeX'><td>{$row['street_number']} {$row['street_name']} {$row['suburb']}</td> ";
        if ($row['service_type'] == $acc1['service_type']) {
            echo "<td>{$$row['cost']}</td>";
        } else {
            // Use single quotes as double quotes will try to evaluate $0 as a variable
            echo '<td>$0</td></tr>';
        }
    } ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" class="text-right"><strong>Total Costs</strong></td>
        <!-- No idea where $row1[1] comes from! -->
        <td colspan="1"><strong>$<?php echo $row1[1]; ?></strong></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi TimBrownlaw, I tried your implementation and had the same result. the MYSQL_ASSOC just needed to become MYSQLI_ASSOC. Thank you so much for your effort in helping me out!!

Comment: Whoops :) I had an inkling I had fudged something... It wasn't meant to solve your problem just more of a guide and a way to debug this. Did you get the outputs from the var_dumps to see whats going on with that bit.